# c# How to find max value in an array containing objects

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, object

I am new to programming and have come to a point in my app where I am really stuck.
I am familiar on how to handle arrays containing single values and bubble sort, but now I am working with an array containing objects from a separate class and want to find the highest value from a private variable in all the objects and print out that object to the user.
The array is empty at first and the user is to fill the array with data.
This is the class:

```
class SoldItem
    {
        private int uniqueId;
        private string itemName;
        private string artist;
        private string itemType;
        private decimal finalPrice;
        private decimal listingPrice;
        private int bidders;

        //Constructor
        public SoldItem(int uniqueId,
            string itemName,
            string artist,
            string itemType,
            decimal finalPrice,
            decimal listingPrice,
            int bidders)
        {
            this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.artist = artist;
            this.itemType = itemType;
            this.finalPrice = finalPrice;
            this.listingPrice = listingPrice;
            this.bidders = bidders;
        }

        //Convert to string method
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Unique id: " + uniqueId +
                "\nItem name: " + itemName +
                "\nBy: " + artist +
                "\nType: " + itemType +
                "\nSold for: " + finalPrice +
                "\nAsking price: " + listingPrice +
                "\nBidders: " + bidders;
        }

        //Public method to access final price from other classes
        public decimal GetFinalPrice()
        {
            return finalPrice;
        }

    }
```

The variable I want to fint the highest value from is finalPrice, any ideas on how to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Thank you for your answers! I am trying to implement the bubble sort method I have used earlier but either I am getting out of range exceptions thrown or the method works but just prints out the last object added in the array regardless of its finalPrice. Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < soldItems.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (soldItems[i] != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < soldItems.Length - i - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (soldItems[j] != null)
                        {
                            if (soldItems[j].GetFinalPrice() > soldItems[i + 1].GetFinalPrice())
                            {
                                highestPrice = soldItems[j].GetFinalPrice();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                highestPrice = soldItems[i].GetFinalPrice();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(highestPrice);
```

Any thoughts? Code above gets out of range exception thrown. Again thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: welcome to SO, your bubble sort approche works here too, but you need to expand it a bit for your usecase. Right now your bubblesort compares 2 numbers, instead of those numbers you just need to call the `GetFinalPrice()` of the objects.

Comment: You'll probably want to either have your class implement [the `IComparable<T>` interfaece](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1); or create a separate class implementing [the `IComparer<T>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1), and pass an instance of that class to the sort method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Linq`.

```
var soldItem = soldItems.MaxBy(soldItem => soldItem.GetFinalPrice());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SoldItem corvette67 = new SoldItem(/*initialize*/);
SoldItem amDB4 = new SoldItem(/*initialize*/);
........
........
.......
DoBubbleSort(corvette67.GetFinalPrice(), amDB4.GetFinalPrice())
{
    // sorting logic
}
```

To access an instance variable you can use the objects(`corvette67` and `amDB4` in this case) of that class. `corvette67` and `amDB4` are our objects to access `SoldItem` class variables that are non-static. If it is a `static` type you want to access, it can be done by using Class name. ex: `SoldItem.SomeStaticMethod()`